# How to use double angle identities to find $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ from $\sin 2x $?

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin 2x =\frac{5}{13}$ and $0^\circ < x < 45^\circ$, find $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

The answers should be $\frac{\sqrt{26}}{26}$ and $\frac{5\sqrt{26}}{26}$

#### Ideas

The idea is to  use double angle identities. One such identity is $\sin 2x=2\sin x\cos x$.

It's easy to use it to find $\sin 2x$ from known $\sin x$ and $\cos x$. But here it's the other way around.

Comment: Do you know the double angle identities? If you write them out, they give you a formula for $\sin(2x)$ in terms of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. You can put $\cos(x)$ in terms of $\sin(x$ using the identity $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$, then solve for $\sin$.

Answer (score 7):

Because we know $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$, it is like solving an equation:
$u^2+v^2 = 1$ and $2uv = 5/13$, $u = \sin(x)$ and $v = \cos(x)$. Hope this helps.

EDIT: oh don't forget to take only the positive roots.

Comment: Thanks That is where I was getting stuck though.... I know that as I work out the problem, I get to where (5/26) = sin(x) cos(x).  Do I continue to make it (5/26) = sin(x) (sqrt 1- sin^2(x))? I'm not sure how to solve from there.  Appreciate the help!

Comment: @Mike:  That works fine.  Now if you square it, you get a quadratic in $\sin^2 x$.  Please, watch the parentheses-when you write "sqrt 1- sin^2(x)" you mean "sqrt (1- sin^2(x))" or $\sqrt {1- \sin^2(x)}$ but it looks like only the $1$ would be under the square root sign.  You can see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for some hints on formatting equations.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\cos ^2(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}(1 + \cos (2x))$, and $\cos (2x) = \dfrac{12}{13}$

Comment: (Some might say that this is more of a "half angle" approach, but the two are intimately linked!)

Comment: Thanks That is where I was getting stuck though.... I know that as I work out the problem, I get to where (5/26) = sin(x) cos(x). Do I continue to make it (5/26) = sin(x) (sqrt 1- sin^2(x))? I'm not sure how to solve from there. Appreciate the help!

Comment: That approach is more in line with the other answer/hint. For mine, just take the square root of $\dfrac{1}{2}(1+\dfrac{12}{13}))$. Then do something similar to find the sine.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we had a right triangle with an angle $2x$, and $\sin2x=\frac{5}{13}$. Further suppose that the hypotenuse of the triangle was 13. We can deduce that the side oppoites $2x$ must be 5. Applying the Pythagorean theorem to find the other side we have
$$13^2=5^2+(\text{adjacent side})^2$$
$$169-25=(\text{adjacent side})^2$$
$$144=(\text{adjacent side})^2$$
implying that the side opposite angle $2x$ is $12$. This allows us to state that
$$\cos 2x=\frac{12}{13}$$
Which is easier to work with because
$$\cos2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x=2\cos^2x-1$$
Substituting we have
$$\frac{12}{13}=2\cos^2x-1$$
$$\cos^2x=\frac{25}{26}$$
$$\cos x=\frac{5}{\sqrt{26}}=\frac{5\sqrt{26}}{26}$$
Applying the Pythagorean identity we have
$$\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$$
$$\frac{25}{26}+\sin^2x=1$$
$$\sin^2x=\frac{1}{26}$$
$$\sin x=\frac{1}{\sqrt{26}}=\frac{\sqrt{26}}{26}$$